# JPA Constraint for date year

Tags: java, jpa, unique-constraint

I have an entity representing Documents that looks like this:

Document
date_creation
doc_number
doc_origin

Documents are usually referred to as *'2012/XY/005'*, that would be the fifth document in 2012 originated by XY.
So number has to be unique in the year it was created and for the same Origin, and I need to put a constraint for it.

What would be the best way to model and map this using JPA?

I think my options are:

**Option 1:** put another field the Document entity for the year in date creation, and make it unique(year,doc_number,doc_origin)

**Option 2:** create a field doc_ref and put a string like 'YEAR/ORIG/NUMBER' and make it unique(doc_ref)

Both options add another field duplicating the year, but Option 1 requires me to update field year consistently with date_creation and Option 2 requires me to update field doc_ref consistently with the rest, so I tend to think that Option 1 is best.

Is there another option that I am not seeing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function-based unique index, if your database allows them. Example in Oracle:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX YEAR_ORIGIN_NUMBER_IDX 
on DOCUMENT (TRUNC(DT_CREATION, 'YEAR'), DOC_ORIGIN, DOC_NUMBER)
```

Comment: yeah, but I need this to work in JPA too, do you know if it's possible?

Comment: A unique constraint is applied on a database table. JPA has not much to do with it. You may define unique constraints using JPA annotations, but these are just used when the JPA implementation creates your database tables (or DDL) for you. In the end, the constraint lives in the database.

Comment: According to the documentation [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_unq.html), the JPA runtime also must take constraint declaration and ensure the order of statements to avoid unique constraint violations.

Comment: Also, I wanted to do the declaration in JPA because I'm trying to do the app database-agnostic, and I'm using Hibernate Tools to generate the DDL.

Comment: Then use the solution uou propose in your question, and make the year field invisible to the outside. Make sure that every method of the entity that modifies the date also modifies the date accordingly.